# Can CNN predict images which have combination of two trained classes?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN, say if we train our model for cats and dogs and if we give an image of cat and giraffe (or any animal). Will it predict the image as cat ?

If I have a use case that I need to predict a cat in a image no matter whatever is in its surroundings(say cat among multiple cats or with other animal), which approach would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you train binary classification CNN model (say cats versus dogs), and the provided image has cat and giraffe, then the model predicts it as `cats` category.

Based on your description, I think you are looking for object detection model. Please check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) for more details. You can use transfer learning approach to train it for your custom classes. Say you trained for two categories (Cats and Dogs), and provide an image that has 10 different animals, the model predicts cats and dogs within that image (if there are any), and draw a bounding box around that and label it as `dog` on top of bounding box around `dog` and similarly for `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if my model needs to classify all the image with *atleast* one cat (along with any number of animals) as class A and those without even a single cat as class B, can image classification be used?

Comment: Based on your description, what you are expecting is difficult to get with good accuracy but not impossible. You model should be able to capture the complexity of capturing cat features are neglect false-positives raised by other animals in the picture. You also need to have good distribution of images representing that complex multi-animal but detect only one.  I think start with simple CNN and add complexity (more CNN layers, dense layers, dropout layers, Maxpooling etc). Try data augmentation also. Best luck.